# My Symfony form errors are always global. Not linked to the specific field like supposed to

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony form where I get errors when the fields are blanks.

I already try to set error_bubbling to false but it still not work (And is supposed to be false by default)

This is my code where I remove everything that is not necessary:

Controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/add", name="add")
     */
    public function add(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { } else { }

        return $this->render('blog/add.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $Title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $Content;
    ...
```

FormType:

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title')
            ->add('content');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Post::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

Form:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>
        Create a post
    </h2>

    {{ form_start(form) }}

        {{ form_widget(form) }}


        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Create" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

When I look at the object after the post all the errors are linked to the form and there's no errors in the childs (The form fields).

[image: Form image]

Does anyone know what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In buildForm(), you need to capitalize your fields. They are case sensitive and they are capitalized in your database.